# Eclipse RCP: Does this make a case for fragment project

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I have a Eclipse RCP plugin which provides some functionality. A part of the functionality is optional and should be provided only when one more plugin is installed.
In such a case should I put this optional functionality in a separate plugin or should I put it in a separate fragment project?
All examples of fragment projects cater to I10N requirements or icons or testing etc. None says that we can remove some part of the functionality into a fragment.

Please comment.

Thanks and regards,

Pradyumna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the normal thing to do is use a separate plugin. Fragments are generally used for code which is specific to a platform or language. They can also be used to change the functionality of classes in the fragment host (this is quick tricky to get working)

As an example in my main RCP project I have 45 plugins and 2 fragments, both fragments provide code that is specific to Macs. Many of the plugins provide functionality which could be considered to be optional.

As usual Lars Vogel has a tutorial on fragments [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFragmentProject/article.html)